# How to handle 'argument list too long' in Makefile recipe?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I use Makefile to control workflow dependency, and the following code causes 'argument too long' error. What would be a good workaround? I am using 3.82 BTW.

```
make: execvp: /bin/sh: Argument list too long
```

Here the logic is to merge all the prerequisites if they are all done (each prerequisite file would have a `.done` sentinel file if it is done/ready).

```
contains=$(foreach v,$2,$(if $(findstring $1,$v),$v,))

.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.merged: $$(call contains,_$$*_,$$(STEP1s))
    if (for x in $^; do [ -f $$x.done ] || exit; done); then \
        for f in $^; do cat $$f; echo; done > $@; fi
```

EDIT: The following recipe doesn't trigger 'argument too long' error.

```
for x in $^;do echo $$x;done
```

Comment: Apparently `$^` is too large for the shell. You could use make macros instead (`foreach`) but this will be extremely slow. Note that, as it is, your subshell always exits wit status 0. So the condition of your `if` statement is always true. Do you want `exit 1` instead of `exit`?

Comment: You have a valid point. Here `exit` is fine because I check the existence of those .merged files when they serve as prerequisites in downstream workflow

Comment: Why would make macros be extremely slow?  Make macros are just string manipulation.  It's a lot faster than invoking a new shell!!

Comment: The last loop is superfluous; you simply want `cat $^` (which of course in theory could also produce "argument list too long"; so perhaps then `echo $^ | xargs cat` with all the complications around nontrivial file names in https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)

Comment: @MadScientist It is not make macros that are slow, it is the very long shell script with many `cat` commands. A probably faster solution would split the long list of file names in small enough chunks but I do not see an easy way to do this.

Comment: @tripleee I use the loop because I need to add a newline between files

Comment: Oh duh, missed that; nvm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for pointing me to the right direction.

I think the problem is that after recipe expansion, `if (for x in $^; do [ -f $$x.done ] || exit; done);` becomes too long

I ended up with this solution, which is somewhat cheating. Here I ignore the prerequisites, and re-compute the prerequisites' sentinels. Then compare their count to an expected value

```
contains=$(foreach v,$2,$(if $(findstring $1,$v),$v,))

.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.merged: $$(call contains,_$$*_,$$(STEP1s))
    if [ $(words $(wildcard *_$(basename $@)_*.txt.done)) == $(n_input) ]; then\
        echo -n $^| xargs -I{} -d' ' sh -c "cat {}; echo " > $@;fi
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: From the various comments it seems that it is the recipe length itself that causes the error, not the length of the arguments of the `for` loops. A way to break it in much smaller pieces would be to introduce intermediate targets, forbid parallel execution, and run make twice, a first time to decide if the target shall be rebuilt and the second time to build it with as many different recipes as there are files to concatenate (not tested):

```
.NOTPARALLEL:

contains=$(foreach v,$2,$(if $(findstring $1,$v),$v$3,))

.SECONDEXPANSION:
ifneq ($(STEM),)
.PHONY: $$(call contains,_$$(STEM)_,$$(STEP1s),.cat)

$(STEM).merged: $$(call contains,_$$(STEM)_,$$(STEP1s),.cat)

%.cat:
    cat $* >> $(STEM).merged
    echo >> $(STEM).merged
else
%.merged: $$(call contains,_$$*_,$$(STEP1s),) $$(call contains,_$$*_,$$(STEP1s),.done)
    $(MAKE) $@ STEM=$*
endif
```

**First version**: Apparently `$^` is too large for the shell. Here is a solution that uses make macros instead of shell loops and that declares the `.done` files as regular prerequisites instead of testing their existence in the recipe:

```
contains=$(foreach v,$2,$(if $(findstring $1,$v),$v $v.done,))

.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.merged: $$(call contains,_$$*_,$$(STEP1s))
    $(foreach f,$(filter-out,%.done,$^),cat "$f" >> "$@"; echo >> "$@";)
```

Comment: The shell itself should be fine with an arbitrarily long argument list; my suspicion is that running a _subshell_ with a really long command is the problem.

Comment: My intuition is that any `for var in $^` fails with the OP's shell. I may be wrong but I don't see how a too long subshell could cause this error message (unless there is a bug in the shell error management and/or error messages).

Comment: The [`ARG_MAX`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/arg-max.html) kernel constant which causes this error message is a feature of the `exec` family of system calls. You should find that e.g. Bash permits a much longer argument line for shell-internal commands like `echo`, `for`, `cd`, etc. But running a subshell obviously crosses an `exec` boundary when the commands for the subshell have to be passed to it.

Comment: Of course, if the shell is some legacy two-bit `sh` implementation, it could have internal limits, too.

Comment: With a small modification of your solution, I get something that logically works, but still triggers the 'argument too long' error. The recipe becomes a long command with many `;`.  For example, one chunk is `cat "achiral_GT_XXVI_2039.txt" >> "GT.merged"; echo >> "GT.merged";`

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the error comes from this recipe? Couldn't it be caused by some other part that you do not show, like, for instance, the way you compute `STEP1s`?

Comment: It fails because make invokes a command like: `/bin/sh -c '<expanded-recipe>'` and if `<expanded-recipe>` is too large it will fail.  The kernel will not allow you to invoke a process with an arbitrarily large command line, even `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Renaud's suggestion meets the stated requirements, which as I understand it is the output is only generated if ALL the prerequisites have a `.done` file.  Also the shell script generated is much longer than needed.

Maybe this will work:

```
contains=$(foreach v,$2,$(if $(findstring $1,$v),$v $v.done,))

.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.merged: $$(call contains,_$$*_,$$(STEP1s))
        $(if $(foreach $F,$^,$(if $(wildcard $F.done),,x)),, \
          for fn in $^; do (cat "$$fn"; echo) >> "$@"; done)
```

You might be able to make this more efficient by avoiding the foreach loop; if you can require GNU make 4.4 you can use `intcmp` to compare the lengths:

```
$(if $(intcmp $(words $^),$(words $(wildcard $(addsuffix .done,$^)))),, \
    ...dostuff...)
```

If not you can probably do the same thing with filtering:

```
$(if $(filter $(words $^),$(words $(wildcard $(addsuffix .done,$^)))), \
    ...dostuff...)
```

Note, none of this is tested.

Comment: Well, in the solution I suggest all `.done` files are prerequisites, if one is missing the rule will not apply and the output will not be generated. And if the OP get an `argument list too long` error with their attempt, the `for fn in $^` you suggest should cause the same error, don't you think?

Comment: Well, yours will be even longer than mine, so it's even worse :).  But, the problem with the OP's original version is that they have the list TWICE: once inside the if statement and again inside the for loop.  In my version the if-statement is done by  make, so it's not passed to the shell.  I guess I don't understand what the `.done` is for but adding it as a prerequisite is a fundamental change to the behavior of the system: it will force the `.done` file to be built if it isn't built already for example.  If that's OK then it's certainly a good solution.

Comment: Oh I see you're thinking that error comes from the shell's for loop.  No, that's not it.  Unless I'm very confused it's coming from the kernel when it tries to START the shell command itself.  The thing that has to be reduced is the total size (number of bytes) of the recipe after expansion.

Comment: Ah, OK, so we cannot exchange the length of the argument list against the length of the shell script.

Comment: Nope.  If the reduced size of the recipe is still too large, the only option is to use `$(words ...)` to try to split it up into multiple individual logical lines in the recipe.  Tricky to do but possible.

Comment: `for x in $^;do :;done` doesn't cause any error, if that helps the discussion